# Set System Resource through MVVM in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have this ViewModel which includes following Property

```
private SolidColorBrush _Color;

public SolidColorBrush LogColor
{
    get { return _Color; }
    set
    {
        _Color = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LogColor"));
    }
}


private LogType _Logtype;

public LogType Logtype
{
    get { return _Logtype; }
    set
    {
        _Logtype = value;
        switch (value)
        {
            case LogType.Info:
                LogColor = System.Windows.SystemColors.ControlTextBrush;
                break;
            case LogType.Warning:
                LogColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.YellowGreen);
                break;
            case LogType.Error:
                LogColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                break;
            case LogType.Success:
                LogColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LawnGreen);
                break;
            default:
                LogColor = System.Windows.SystemColors.ControlTextBrush;
                break;
        }
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Logtype"));
    }
}
```

The Binding is working fine with the SolidColorBrush as `System.Windows.SystemColors.ControlTextBrush` but problem starts when theme is changed to dark. So I need to use the `System.Windows.SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey`. Now I can't find any resource which can help me in the situation. `FrameworkElement.SetResourceReference` method would do it but I don't see that from MVVM point.
So is there any way I can set this dynamic resource to my control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
LogColor = (Brush)Application.Current.FindResource(
                     System.Windows.SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey);
```